# Use VBA to look up a value in a column, then sum up the value in the adjacent column

Tags: vba, excel

I have a table like this:

```
 Name   Variation   Type    No_of_unit_sold

 Apple   FG72H       1         12
 Apple   FG72H       1         17
 Apple   FG72H       1         61
 Apple   FG73H       1          1
 Apple   FG74H       1          3
 Orange  OO20        1          3
 Orange  OO20        1          4
 Orange  OO20        1        117
 Orange  OO20        1          0
 Orange  OO20        1          4
 Orange  OO21        2         15
 Grape   G7TY        1         110
 Grape   G7TY        1          65
 Grape   G7TY        3          53
 Grape   G7TY        3          31
 Grape   G7TY        1          12
 Grape   G7TY        1          1
```

The actual table is about 39000 rows long.

So I need to look for type `1` (there's 1 to 32) in column `Type`

then sum up the corresponding `No_of_unit_sold` and place the result at the bottom row of `No_of_unit_sold`.

```
Worksheets("All Fruits").Activate
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim rng As Range

    Worksheets(name).Activate


    lastrow = Range("C2").End(xlDown).Row
    For i = 1 to 32
         Set rng = Range("D:D").Find(what = i)

         '???????????

         Cells(lastrow, 5).Offset(1, 0).Select
         Cells(lastrow, 5).Offset(1, 0) = "=Sum(D2:D" & lastrow & ")"
     Next i
 End Sub
```

I need suggestion at the `????` part.

Comment: Why do you use VBA for that? I think that should be possible with a simple `=SUMIF()` formula.

Comment: because there are 32 types of fruits for me to scan from 39000 rows, in addition to over 50 worksheets that I have to clean, and I have to send the output to the 51th sheet.... so this is just a small part of that massive process. Yep I guess sumif should be good. Thanks for your suggestion

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do that with formulas only (no need for VBA).

Assuming the data in your example where `Type` is column C and `No_of_unit_sold` is column D. You could use in column E:

```
=SUMIF(C:C,1,D:D)  'to sum all units of type 1
=SUMIF(C:C,2,D:D)  'to sum all units of type 2
…
=SUMIF(C:C,32,D:D) 'to sum all units of type 32
```

---

Or what I used in G in the example below is:

```
=SUMIF(C:C,F:F,D:D)
```

*Note that you need to put the results into a new column, not in the same column as `No_of_unit_sold` because this would calculate wrong then.*

[image]

Answer (score 1):

As @Pᴇʜ said, best solution would be a pure SUMIF. No need of VBA.

In case you need to do it with VBA for any reasons, there is always an VBA version of each formula available in Excel if you use [Application.WorksheetFunction Property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/excel-vba/articles/application-worksheetfunction-property-excel).

For my code, I used [WorksheetFunction.SumIf method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.interop.excel.worksheetfunction.sumif.aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=vb#code-snippet-1)

My code just pops up a Msgbox with the sum of `No_of_unit_sold` if `Type=1`.

```
Sub Macro1()
Dim LastRow As Long 'to save the last row number of column TYPE with data

LastRow = Range("C" & Range("C:C").Rows(Range("C:C").Rows.Count).Row).End(xlUp).Row

MsgBox Application.WorksheetFunction.SumIf(Range("C2:C" & LastRow), 1, Range("D2:D" & LastRow))
End Sub
```

Adapt it tou your needs.

Answer (score 0):

Try this below code. Use `if` condition to check your criteria and then get the corresponding value from column D and add it to final `Total`.

```
Sub Typee()

Dim TotalType As Integer
Dim Total As Integer
Total = 0

TotalType = Range("C2").End(xlDown).Row

For i = 2 To TotalType
If Sheets("Sheet1").Range("C" & i).Value = 1 Then
Total = Total + Sheets("Sheet1").Range("D" & i).Value
End If
Next

MsgBox Total

End Sub
```